# Regex for something similar to left trim but replace white spaces with html equivalent

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

need help transforming the following string `"     Hello I have blanks to the left"` into something like `"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hello I have blanks to the left"`.  Have tried matching multiple blanks to the left but it only replaces all of the blanks with a single `"&nbsp"`.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. My preferred way would be:

```
preg_replace_callback("/^ +/",function($m) {return str_repeat("&nbsp;",strlen($m));},$input);
```

Note that if you have PHP older than 5.3, you will need to use `create_function` instead of directly putting an anonymous callback in there.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely does the trick.  Just out of curiosity what are the other ways you might tackle this problem?

Comment: Well, I know there are some, but I can't think of them now - it's gone midnight XD